# David Austin rose from pot growing low on the ground

Tags: planting, roses

I bought the pot of this last Fall

https://www.davidaustinroses.com/us/the-poet-s-wife-shrub-rose

But over the Winter it looks smaller and sit flat on the ground

[image]

Is that normal or is it not doing well?

Comment: There's so much leaf litter all over it, it's quite hard to tell what's going on with it - is it planted in the ground or still in a pot, and what's the rusty iron grid behind it? Either way, the rose is not dead, plenty of green on it...

Comment: Looks like a rabbit may have chewed off the main stem, or it was torn off at some point, but otherwise the rose looks fine. Give it a few weeks and you should see some more new growth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I live in Texas and we expose the crown of the plant. I understand that they do bury it up North to help protect it in the Winter. It looks like it's getting what it needs. I had this rose before the Witch's Broom disease swept through our neighborhood and overtook some roses before I could prune it out. It's a pretty yellow rose with a very nice fragrance!