# Rose has small leaves maybe nutrition issue?

Tags: leaves, roses, nutrients

I bought this rose from David Austin

https://www.davidaustinroses.com/us/the-poet-s-wife-shrub-rose

It had rabbit eating the top part down to the ground in beginning. My past question

[David Austin rose from pot growing low on the ground](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/49484/david-austin-rose-from-pot-growing-low-on-the-ground)

Now several months later the leaves coming back but I wonder if the leaves are too small:

[image]

Is it normal or too small? If not normal, should I do something about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leaves look normal to me for leaves on a recently planted bush. Maybe a little too light green, but normally this is taken care of in normal soil as the roots expand.  Let the leaves get a bit older and they may turn glossy deep green. If you are concerned about soil quality then soil tests are available. It looks like you have some kind of chipped mulch on the soil; we might recommend top dressing with compost or well rotted manure but this would be more difficult if you have to remove the mulch first. Roses require a lot of feed, so a mulch of mature manure might be preferable to bark chips.